# kernel routines linux ubuntu and redhat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat

I am searching for a command to display the source code of kernel functions (e.g blk_make_request) in my monitor instead of looking for them in the google. Especially for redhat and ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get hold of the Linux source code first, which is not available on Ubuntu by default.

You could either enable Ubuntu's source repositories, but it's easier to get the source from Github.

If you don't have git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then to get Linux:

```
git clone git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git  # This will take a long time, it's about 1.1 GB
cd linux
git grep blk_make_request
```

This will show you where to look.